# Tried running this grabCut algorithm found online on android phone but failed and crashed

Tags: android

i tried running this on my android phone but it crashes upon running. Need 
help on this as i'm still a newbie in android programming and in the midst 
of learning it.

```
package com.example.cklim.opencv_test2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;





public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
ImageView imageView;
Bitmap bitmap;
Canvas canvas;
Scalar color = new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255);
Point tl, br;
int counter;
Bitmap bitmapResult, bitmapBackground;
Mat dst = new Mat();
final String pathToImage  = "/mnt/sdcard/gcut.png";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToImage);
    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Press top left and bottom right of the      foreground image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    msg.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);

    msg.show();
    bitmapResult = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true);
    canvas = new Canvas(bitmapResult);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapResult);
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);

    tl = new Point();
    br = new Point();
    counter = 0;
}

//@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (counter == 0) {
            tl.x = event.getX();
            tl.y = event.getY();
            counter++;
        } else if (counter == 1) {
            br.x = event.getX();
            br.y = event.getY();
            counter++;

            Mat img = new Mat();
            img = Imgcodecs.imread(pathToImage);
            Mat background = new Mat();
            try {
                background = Utils.loadResource(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.drawable.wall2 );
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            backgroundSubtracting(img, background);
            Imgcodecs.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/GRABCUT/rect.png", dst);
            Bitmap jpg = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/GRABCUT/rect.png");

            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(jpg);
            imageView.invalidate();
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private void backgroundSubtracting(Mat img, Mat background) {
    Mat firstMask = new Mat();
    Mat bgModel = new Mat();
    Mat fgModel = new Mat();
    Mat mask;
    Mat source = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(3.0));
    dst = new Mat();
    Rect rect = new Rect(tl, br);

    Imgproc.grabCut(img, firstMask, rect, bgModel, fgModel, 1, 0 /* GC_INIT_WITH_RECT */);
    Core.compare(firstMask, source/* GC_PR_FGD */, firstMask, Core.CMP_EQ);

    Mat foreground = new Mat(img.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(255,
            255, 255));
    img.copyTo(foreground, firstMask);

    Imgproc.rectangle(img, tl, br, color);

    Mat tmp = new Mat();
    Imgproc.resize(background, tmp, img.size());
    background = tmp;
    mask = new Mat(foreground.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));

    Imgproc.cvtColor(foreground, mask, 6/* COLOR_BGR2GRAY */);
    Imgproc.threshold(mask, mask, 254, 255, 1 /* THRESH_BINARY_INV */);

    Mat vals = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(0.0));
    background.copyTo(dst);

    background.setTo(vals, mask);
    Core.add(background, foreground, dst, mask);

    firstMask.release();
    source.release();
    bgModel.release();
    fgModel.release();
    vals.release();
}
```

}

[here's the logcat output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLe3I.png)

please help me out on this. thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Post your logcat output..

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Are you using android studio? Did you use static initialization?

Comment: yes i'm using android studio. static initialization? don quite get you.

Comment: Can you give me a link to this sample project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy compiled library from OpenCV SDK into your application.

1. Go to opencv-android-sdk/sdk/native
2. Copy **libs** folder into your **app/src/main** and rename it to **jniLibs**
3. Add `static{ System.loadLibrary("opencv_java"); }` to activity to load OpenCV library.

Hope it helps you..